# Is it worth it to go to one of those online workshops if you don't have a degree?

Tags: career-development

Is it worth it to pay for those online learning courses such as www.lynda.com for services in developing web design business education 3D + animation video if you don't have a degree or certification will companies take you serious?

Comment: do you want to take the course in order to learn, or just for a certificate?

Comment: I would be wanting to take the course to get certified in a new skill.

Comment: In my experience online certificates are not worth much depending who they're from. A MCP from microsoft or the A+ certifications are recognised, but most others are just paper. You can basically buy a Masters degree in any subject online based solely on what you tell them is your life experience.

Comment: What if I am  were to do an online course you  would suggest one of those two you just mentioned ?

Comment: depends what you want to be certified in, those are entry level, way back when I took them I didn't do a course, just bought the books, went through them and sat the exam online at a certified testing centre when I was ready.

Comment: I also train a couple of local boys every six months to pass the exam, but I'm not handing out my own certification, I just prepare them to sit the Microsoft exam.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it worth it to pay for those online learning courses

It depends on how and what knowledge you gain from these courses. So, let me put this from a technical interviewer point of view:

If it is an accredited certification, then I might take them serious. But, if they are from Lynds or Coursera, Udacity, etc; then you cannot escape from the preliminary tests.

**Why?**

Because the code and materials for acing the tests and earning certifications are all over the internet. So, it is not very difficult for a student to attempt plagiarism and earn a certificate there.

So, it totally depends upon the type of certification

Answer (score 3):

It depends very much on the certification you get. Accredited certification such as the Microsoft ones are worth having. Unknown ones specific to the website are less useful. So if it's a course that eventually gets you a internationally recognised certification from Microsoft or Adobe or similar then it is worth the outlay, the course would just be prep, the actual certification exam would be sat at a registered and certified exam centre.

Although some large software vendors will provide a complete course and certification all online specific to their product.

Anything less is a waste of money, you can basically buy a Masters degree in any subject online based solely on what you tell them is your life experience. So anything not mainstream is suspect from the start in most interviewers eyes.